# Elastic Binary Search Tree in Haproxy

Tags: haproxy

I just look at the source of HAproxy to learn about how is it implemented , and I see an interesting data structure called [Elastic Binary Search tree](https://github.com/haproxy/ebtree). It seems to be very similar to binary search tree. But I would like to know what is the different and the reason behind choosing this data structure for load balancer.

Answer (score 9):

You'll find the implementation details here : http://1wt.eu/articles/ebtree/

In short, the main difference between a regular binary tree and ebtree s that in a regular binary tree, you need to allocate intermediary nodes to attach leaves, and in some environments, having to allocate a node in the middle just to insert a leaf is not convenient. With ebtrees, each structure is both a node and a leaf, and thanks to some pointer manipulation, both of them can be used separately. And this possibility comes with a number of interesting properties described in the article above such as O(1) removal, support for duplicate keys, etc...

The benefit of using ebtrees in haproxy compared to rbtrees is the O(1) removal which makes ebtrees much faster than rbtrees for the scheduler where entries are constantly added/removed. And compared to BST (which was the original design leading to ebtrees), insertion is very fast (no malloc) and remoal doesn't require a free().

A new version is under development to save space. It will have the same complexity as rbtrees but with smaller memory usage. This will be useful to store lots of data which are often looked up and rarely removed (eg: haproxy's stick tables, caches, ...).